# have problem with MVC, String not Showing in the Return View

Tags: c#, string, view

in the Controller:

```
       public ActionResult Create()
            {
                int i = 0;
                string s = "";
                bool unique = false;

                while (!unique)
                {
                    s = GenerateCode(i);

                    var CheckURLs = from x in db.QRCodeGs
                            where x.QRCodeShortString == s
                            select new { ShortCode = x.QRCodeShortString};
                    if (CheckURLs.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        unique = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }


        return View(new QRCodeG { QRCodeShortString = s, QRCodeGenDate =    DateTime.Today, LastEditDate = DateTime.Today, LastEditor = User.Identity.Name });

            //return View();
           }
```

Create.cshtml page:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QRCodeShortString)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QRCodeShortString) <br />(You make   choose your own string or use this dynamically generated one)
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?  Please be more descriptive in your question.

Comment: the QRCodeShortString = s is not showing up.

Comment: more specifically, I am looking to pre-populate the editorfor field. If I am pre-generating an object of type model, displayfor will work, and hiddenfor will work, but editorfor does not recognize that I have already created an object with some information in it. We use the displayfor and hiddenfor workaround for some other data such as the last modified date which we don't want the user to provide their own data for, but our dynamically generated code is only a suggestion for them (the next available in our base-whatever encoding), and they are free to enter their own

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what the problem is, but here's a few things to check

1. Make sure the model is the proper type in the cshtml page.  ie: @model QRCodeG
2. Make sure the variable 's' actually has something in it
3. Check your css (editor-field class) to make sure you aren't hiding it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing I would suggest is to move where you declare the model you are passing to the view, do something like

```
var qrCodeG = new QRCodeG { QRCodeShortString = s, QRCodeGenDate =    DateTime.Today, LastEditDate = DateTime.Today, LastEditor = User.Identity.Name };
return qrCodeG;
```

then use the debugger to see if qrCodeG is being populated correctly.

if that works then try adding

```
<div> @model.QRCodeShortString </div>
```

to your view and see if that is outputting your data correctly

if that works look at what is going on in @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QRCodeShortString)

Comment: Thank you. We got it. The variable 's' actually droped.